# Can someone please tell me why the out.println isn't working?

Tags: java, jdbc

the JDBC code below inserts data into a table in a MySQL database. It is working fine, except for the out.println response and the requestdispatcher. When update is successful, it should print "Employee Account successfully created". And similarly if update is unsuccessful. However, it is not printing the output.

```
        try{ 

             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
             Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payroll_system", "root", ""); 
             PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO payroll_system.employee_info(employeeID, FirstName, LastName, Admin,DOB,Address,Email,HourlyRate,Gender,ALeaveBalance,SLeaveBalance,ActiveStatus,Role,BSB,BankName,AccNumber,SuperNumber,SuperCompany) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,1,?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
             ps.setString(1, employee_id);
             ps.setString(2, firstName);
             ps.setString(3, lastName);
             ps.setString(4, admin);
             ps.setString(5, DOB);
             ps.setString(6, address);
             ps.setString(7, email);
             ps.setString(8, HPR);
             ps.setString(9, gender);
             ps.setString(10, ALB);
             ps.setString(11, SLB);
             ps.setString(12, Role);
             ps.setString(13, BSB);
             ps.setString(14, BankName);
             ps.setString(15, BAN);
             ps.setString(16, SAC);
             ps.setString(17, SAN);

             int count = ps.executeUpdate(); 

             if(count>0) { 
                 out.println("Employee Account Successfully Created");
             }
             else { 
                 out.println("Failed to create account");
             }

         }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: just my 2 cents: Servlet should never contain any SQL operations.

Comment: @BalusC Sorry, I'm new to web applications. What exactly does that mean?

Comment: @BalusC Ah, thanks! By the way the else { part is not printing whenever the insert is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `executeUpdate` twice, the second call will return nothing, you should remove a call .

So, just replace :

```
ps.executeUpdate(); 

int count = ps.executeUpdate();
```

with :

```
int count = ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks! haha my bad.

Comment: By the way, just curious, the employee_id in my table is a primary key. If the servlet attempts to insert an employee_id that already exists, will that cause the insert to fail?

Comment: Sure, MySQL will give an error about a primary key violation, that will get you an SQLException .

Comment: Your catch block will catch this error, but you may want to add a catch(_SQLException_) clause , because catch(Exception) will catch any Exception, not just SQL ones .